# Failed to load driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from HikariConfig class classloader ParallelWebapp

Tags: database, jdbc, artifactory, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to install Artifactory latest version 7.x and while configuring Microsoft SQL Database with JFrog Artifactory, it is failing with error - System.yaml not validated.

system.yaml file:

```
database:    
    driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url:  "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx:1433;databaseName=artifactory;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;applicationName=Artifactory Binary Repository"
    username: artifactory
    password: xxxxx
```

Steps followed:

1. Downloaded JDBC driver from : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58505
2. Executed the sqljdbc_7.4.1.0_enu.exe file and I saw following jar files present under sqljdcd7.4/enu folder

   example: mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar

Hence I downloaded sqljdbc.jar file from some location into
"artifactory_home/artifactory/bootstarp/artifactory/tomcat/lib and started artifactory.bat file.

But it's failing with below error:

> [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Failed to load driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from HikariConfig class classloader ParallelWebappClassLoader

Answer (score 0):

can you share the complete system.yaml as well as the complete log stacktrace of the error? For me system.yaml seems to be incorrect, it should be as

```
shared: 
 database: 
  driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  url: "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx:1433;databaseName=artifactory;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;applicationName=Artifactory Binary Repository"
  username: artifactory
  password: xxxxx
```

Also, the jar is compatible with Java8 and not with Java11, can you check for a jar as mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre11.jar and place it correctly. If you get the same error again with the correct JAR file placed follow this [JFrog KB article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-resolve-caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-datatypeconverter-when-upgrading-to-artifactory-7-x/) for the same.

Comment: I have tried everything possible, this system.yaml is failing to validate.